# String with the highest frequency of recurring letters in a word

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

This is a challenge for coderbyte I thought I'd try to do it using a different method for solving it than loops, objects. It passed but it isn't perfect. The directions for the challenge are:

*Have the function LetterCountI(str) take the str parameter being passed and return the first word with the greatest number of repeated letters. For example: "Today, is the greatest day ever!" should return greatest because it has 2 e's (and 2 t's) and it comes before ever which also has 2 e's. If there are no words with repeating letters return -1. Words will be separated by spaces.*

```
 function LetterCountI(str){
  var wordsAndLetters = {};   
  var count = 0;
  var finalword;
  str = str.split(" ");
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    wordsAndLetters[str[i]] = wordsAndLetters[str[i]] || 0;
  }
  function countWordLetters(strs){
    strs = strs.split("");
    var lettercount = {};
    for(var i = 0; i <strs.length; i++){
      lettercount[strs[i]] = lettercount[strs[i]] || 0;
      lettercount[strs[i]]++;
    }
    return lettercount;
  }
  for(var words in wordsAndLetters){
    wordsAndLetters[words] = countWordLetters(words);
    var highestLetterFrequency = wordsAndLetters[words];
    for(var values in highestLetterFrequency){
      if(highestLetterFrequency[values] > count){
        count = highestLetterFrequency[values];
        finalword = words;
      }
      if(count !== 1){
        return finalword;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
LetterCountI("today is the greatest day ever!");
```

Sorry if some of the variable names are confusing I've been up for far too long trying to figure out what I did wrong. If you use the parameters at the bottom of the code it returns 'greatest' like it should however change the parameters to

```
LetterCountI("toddday is the greatttttest day ever!");
```

and it logs 'toddday' when it should log 'greatttttest'. Is my code completely wrong? I realize if the parameters were ("caatt dooog") it should log 'caatt' since there are 4 recurring letters but I'm not worried about that I just am concerned about it finding the most recurrence of one letter(but by all means if you have a solution I would like to hear it!). Any changes to the variables if needed to make this code more readable would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure "caatt dooog" should return "caatt"? I would say the requirement is to return "dooog" for a 3 letter repeat, as opposed to "caatt" which only has 2 letter repeat, albeit twice

Comment: I was just saying since if we were following the coderbyte instructions here caatt would have more recurring letters.

Comment: But that is what I am saying, the instructions you have posted are a bit misleading and I think you have interpreted them wrong. The clue being that the requirements have given a repeat value of 2 for greatest, rather than 4 which would fit your rules in the "caatt dooog" example

Comment: Using underscore you could do this in a few lines... I can prepare an answer if you want an alternative approach.

Comment: [Here's an alternative solution..](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5KVY6/1125/). I am not putting this as an answer because this doesn't answer your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the positioning of the following section of code:

```
if(count !== 1){
    return finalword;
}
```

Move it from where it currently is to just before the `return -1`, like so:

```
for(var words in wordsAndLetters){
    wordsAndLetters[words] = countWordLetters(words);
    var highestLetterFrequency = wordsAndLetters[words];
    for(var values in highestLetterFrequency){
      if(highestLetterFrequency[values] > count){
        count = highestLetterFrequency[values];
        finalword = words;
      }
    }
}
if(count !== 1){
    return finalword;
}
return -1;
```

The problem with your original code is that your were returning the first word that had repeating characters, which meant your code didn't get far enough to check if any subsequent words had more repeating characters.

Also, just for fun, [here is my alternative solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jT7gt/).

Comment: Nice thanks @musefan very helpful seems like I spaced that in my sleepy delirious like state :)

Answer (score 0):

[**Here you go**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/QHRq4/)

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}

function LetterCountI(str){
    var temp = str.split(" ");
    var final = '', weight = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i) {
        var word = temp[i].split("");
        if(word.getUnique().length < word.length) {
            var diff = word.length - word.getUnique().length;
            if(diff > weight){
                weight = diff;
                final = temp[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return final;
}

console.log(LetterCountI("Catt dooog"));
console.log(LetterCountI("toddday is the greatttttest day ever!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Viva LinQ !!!!!

```
    var resultPerWord = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    var S = "toddday is the greatttttest day ever!";

    foreach(var s in S.Split(' ')) 
    {
        var theArray =
            from w in s
            group w by w into g
            orderby g.Count() descending
            select new { Letter = g.Key, Occurrence = g.Count() };

        resultPerWord.Add(s, theArray.First().Occurrence);
    }

    var r = "-1";
    if (resultPerWord.Any(x => x.Value >1))
    {
        r = resultPerWord.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First().Key;
    }
```